# Two actions on the same page

Tags: django

At the moment, I have two functionalities on two pages:

- List all orders(/orders)
- Create a new order(/create)

I would like to to be able to create an order on the same page as listing.

In my urls.py:

```
url(r'^create/$', views.OrderCreateView.as_view(),name='create'),
```

In my forms.py:

```
class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = models.TransDetails
    fields = ("__all__")
```

In my views.py:

```
class PlaceListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
  login_url = '/login/'
  context_object_name='placeList'
  model= models.Places
  template_name = 'transadmin/place_list.html'

  def get_queryset(self):
    return models.Places.objects.all().order_by('pname')

class PlaceCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
  login_url = '/login/'
  form_class = PlaceCreateForm
  success_url = reverse_lazy("transadmin:place_list")
  template_name = 'transadmin/create_place.html'
```

I have tried adding a form on the listing page to add but when submit nothing is happening. How do I go about this?

EDIT:

template:

```
    {% extends "transadmin/base.html" %} {% block body_block %} {% if user.is_superuser %}
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="x_panel">
    <div class="row x_title">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Orders</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table id="orderTable" class="table" data-editing="true" data-paging-size="5" data-paging="true" data-filtering="true" data-sorting="true" data-state="false">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th data-breakpoints="xs sm">Origin</th>
                <th data-breakpoints="xs sm">Destination</th>
                <th data-breakpoints="xs sm md">Mode</th>
                <th>Status</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for order in orderList %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{order.id}}</td>
                <td>{{order.origin}} </td>
                <td>{{order.mode}} </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="x_panel">
    <div class="x_title">
        <h3>Create an order</small></h3>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="x_content">
        <br />

        <div class="form-group">
            <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
                {% csrf_token %} {{ form|bootstrap_horizontal }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-6">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-success pull-right" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please post the template code.

Comment: @alfonso.kim i have added template code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the `action` parameter in the form declaration:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'transadmin:create' %}"
      class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
    {% csrf_token %} {{ form|bootstrap_horizontal }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-6">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-success pull-right" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I have tried this but the form is still not submitting anything

Comment: When I click submit on this form, it is redirecting me to the page /create

Comment: I see. What is the `action` url that is rendered in the `create` view?

Comment: Apologies. My mistake. I did not include the textbox. It works now. Thanks!